# Difference between dates calculation not working

Tags: php, date

I have the following code which calculates the amount of 'borg' according to the difference in days. I echoe'd out my `$days`variable to check how many days the difference is. According to that, the difference I have for one particular day is 38 days. How come that when I echo `$borg`, it still displays the amount of 0 ? In this example, `$days = 38`.

```
$vandaag = date($format, strtotime('today'));
$verschil = $interval->d;
$diff = strtotime($retourdatum) - strtotime($vandaag);

$days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));
echo $days;
if($days > 0)
{
    $borg = 80;
}
if($days<0 && $days>-7)
{
    $borg = 65;
}
if($days>-7 && $days<-14)
{
    $borg = 50;
}
if($days>-14 && $days<-21)
{
    $borg = 35;
}
if($days>-21 && $days<-28)
{
    $borg = 20;
}
if($days>-28 && $days<-35)
{
    $borg = 5;
}
else
{
    $borg = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last two conditional blocks are the cause of this *particular* problem:

```
if($days>-28 && $days<-35)
{
    $borg = 5;
}
else
{
    $borg = 0;
}
```

The first applies whenever `$days` is greater than negative 28 *and* less than negative 35, *at the same time*. This is impossible, so the `else` always applies, and `$borg` is always zero. All your other `if` statements aren't linked to these last two in any way, so they're always evaluated. At least three of your other `if`'s have the same problem: they set up a condition that's impossible to fulfill.

I *think* this is what you're trying to do: have a value for `$borg` that gets smaller as `$days` gets more negative. If you use `else if` conditions, you don't have to repeat and reverse the previous condition every time, and it's easier to see what you're doing (helpful when, say, you've accidentally flipped `<` and `>`):

```
$borg = 0;

if($days > 0)
{
    $borg = 80;
}
else if ($days > -7)
{
    $borg = 65;
}
else if ($days > -14)
{
    $borg = 50;
}
else if ($days > -21)
{
    $borg = 35;
}
else if ($days > -28)
{
    $borg = 20;
}
else if ($days > -35)
{
    $borg = 5;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your last `else` will always set `$borg` to 0 unless its corresponding `if` was evaluated.

The solution is to define `$borg = 0;` BEFORE all of your `if` statements, and get rid of the `else` statement.

```
 $borg = 0;
 if( ... )
 {
 }
 ...
```

Comment: Am I really that stupid.. ? Thanks! Been stuck on it for like two hours :(

Answer (score 1):

I did not really understood what you are calculating, but I clearly see why you always have 0 in borg.

The following code should resolve your problem :

```
$vandaag = date($format, strtotime('today'));
$verschil = $interval->d;
$diff = strtotime($retourdatum) - strtotime($vandaag);
$days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));
echo $days;
if($days > 0)
{
    $borg = 80;
}
elseif($days<0 && $days>-7)
{
    $borg = 65;
}
elseif($days>-7 && $days<-14)
{
    $borg = 50;
}
elseif($days>-14 && $days<-21)
{
    $borg = 35;
}
elseif($days>-21 && $days<-28)
{
    $borg = 20;
}
elseif($days>-28 && $days<-35)
{
    $borg = 5;
}
else
{
    $borg = 0;
}
```

This way the $borg = 0 code will only be executed if all the statements are false.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using elseif. You do each if calculation and then end it with an if/else state. The result is $borg can either be 5 or 0.

```
if($days > 0)
    $borg = 80;
elseif($days<0 && $days>-7)
    $borg = 65;
elseif($days>-7 && $days<-14)
    $borg = 50;
elseif($days>-14 && $days<-21)
    $borg = 35;
elseif($days>-21 && $days<-28)
    $borg = 20;
elseif($days>-28 && $days<-35)
    $borg = 5;
else
    $borg = 0;
```

Read over the documentation here: [elseif](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php).